# Drupal query insert after select

Tags: database, drupal

how can i do :

$sql = db_select table A (juste few fields)
join **table B** (with fields that are same with fields from table A)
condition
...

$sql = db_insert (**table B**)
with fields (fields are both from table A and from a form (textfields..) from table B)

Thank you

Comment: Why using custom queries? Why not read content with views and save nodes?

Comment: thanx for helpin, but i'm working on an admin back office (without displaying forms on nodes) that's why i'm not using views

Comment: "without displaying forms on nodes"? What does that have to do with using views?

Comment: You could always construct a view that does what you want, then just copy the sql.

Comment: hi, i mean i dont want to have a node id for displayed form, i wanna have a all displayed on an admin "interface"